# Python2.3.4 for Damnsmall Linux OS version2.4.26 on i686

Tags: python, linux

1. I downloaded the python2.3.tar.gz
2. I installed it and started the interpreter
3. I import Tkinter but get and error message

   ```
   File "/opt/python/lib/python2.3/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 38, in ?
   import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
   ImportError: No module named _tkinter
   ```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you need to use software that old?

Answer (score 2):

The `Tkinter` Python module has a number of dependencies (including Tk and X11) which must have not been installed, or not installed correctly, when you configured and built Python.

Also, Python 2.3 is positively ancient. You may want to try again with a more recent version.